# How to Split a String to remove certain Parts

Tags: java, split

I have a File that COntains Strings in This Format:

```
ACHMU)][2:s,161,(ACH Payment Sys Menus - Online Services)][3:c,1,(M)][4:c,1,(N)]
ACLSICZ)][2:s,161,(Report for Auto Closure)][3:c,1,(U)][4:c,1,(N)]
ACMPS)][2:s,161,(Account Maintenance-Pre-shipment Account)][3:c,1,(U)][4:c,1,(N)]
ACNPAINT)][2:s,161,(Interest Run For NPA Accounts)][3:c,1,(U)][4:c,1,(N)]
```

I need to Split the String so that I have the data in this Format:

```
ACHMU (ACH Payment Sys Menus - Online Services)
ACLSICZ (Report for Auto Closure)......
```

Basically, I want to remove the ")[2:s,161," part and the "][3:c,1,(M)][4:c,1,(N)]" at the end. Will Splitting the String Help Me? The following Method has already failed:

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(C:/Test.txt);
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
String str;
while((str = br.readLine()) != null){
    String[] split = str.Split(")[2:s,161,")
}
```

Please Help me get the Junk in the middle and at the end.

Comment: is there any error or exception that you get after String[] split = str.Split(")[2:s,161,")?

Comment: No error, just that the String does not get Split.

Comment: use regex as nhahtdh mentioned.

Comment: @Stanley will `)][2:s,161,` part always remain the same or it can change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
str.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\)\\].*?(\\(.*?\\))\\].*", "$1 $2");
```

Comment: This Code gives the Correct Answer but in  single Line. Is there a way to Keep Each Output in its Own Line? The Ouput Looks Like  ACHMU (ACH Payment Sys Menus - Online Services)ACLSICZ (Report for Auto Closure)

Comment: `str.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\)\\].*?(\\(.*?\\))\\].*", "$1 $2\n)`  This is the right Answer I wanted.........Thank you Sir.

Comment: @Stanley: Output depends on how you print it out. If you use `System.out.println` then a new line will be added for you.

Answer (score 3):

The straight-forward way, use `substring()` and `indexOf()`:

```
String oldString = "ACHMU)][2:s,161,(ACH Payment Sys Menus - Online Services)][3:c,1,(M)][4:c,1,(N)]";
String firstPart = oldString.substring(0, oldString.indexOf(")")); // ACHMU
String secondPart = oldString.substring(oldString.indexOf("(")); // (ACH Payment Sys Menus - Online Services)][3:c,1,(M)]
String newString = firstPart + " " + secondPart.substring(0, secondPart.indexOf(")") + 1); // ACHMU (ACH Payment Sys Menus - Online Services)
System.out.print(newString);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> ACHMU (ACH Payment Sys Menus - Online Services)

Comment: ACHMU (ACH Payment Sys Menus - Online Services)][2:s,161,(Report for Auto Closure)][3:c,1,(U)][4:c,1,(N)]
ACLSICZ (Report for Auto Closure)][2:s,161,(Account Maintenance-Pre-shipment Account)][3:c,1,(U)][4:c,1,(N)]
ACMPS (Account Maintenance-Pre-shipment Account)][2:s,161,(Interest Run For NPA Accounts)][3:c,1,(U)][4:c,1,(N)]

Answer (score 2):

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(C:/Test.txt);
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
String str;
String newStr;
String completeNewStr="";
while((str = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    newStr = str.replace(")][2:s,161,"," ");
    newStr = str.replace("][3:c,1,(M)][4:c,1,(N)]","");
    completeNewStr+=newStr;
}

// completeNewStr is your final string
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string that you want to replace is always "[2:s,161," , replace it with a empty string or space if that's acceptable. Similarly, for the other string as well.

```
str.replace("[2:s,161,", '');
```